# Mostrar e esconder, vindo do banco

Tags: php, jquery

Estou fazendo essa função

```
<script>

function ver_endereco(){
    $("tr.tr_end").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Nesse código PHP

```
<?php 
            while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {

                ?>

            <tr class="tr_lista">
                <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td><td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row['forma_pagamento'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['observacao'];?></td><td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row['data_pedido'];?></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Ver mercadorias" onclick="ver_endereco();"/></td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="tr_end">
            <td colspan="5">
                <textarea rows="7" cols="90" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;"><?php echo $row['mercadoria'];?></textarea>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

o problema é que o efeito toogle está mostrando todas as tr listadas pelo while, e eu quero que mostre somente a tr que eu estou clicando com o botão "Ver_endereço".
Como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Em `$("tr.tr_end").toggle()` o JavaScript irá buscar todas as linhas que possuem a classe `tr_end`, que são todas, aparentemente. Para ativar apenas a que você está pressionando, você precisa passar algum identificador único por parâmetro da função.

Comment: esse é o problema, eu não to conseguindo passar o identificador que vem do php para a função do javascript, por que parece que o javascript não aceita strings com quebra de linhas, e o texto que vem do banco que poderia identificar a TR esta vindo com quebras de linhas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já que está usando jQuery, poderias usar os métodos da biblioteca, como o evento `.click`, que dispensa o uso do `onclick` e da função `ver_endereco()`.

**Veja:**

```js
$(":button", ".tr_lista").click(function(){
   
   $(this)
   .closest("tr")
   .next(".tr_end")
   .toggle();
   
});
```

```css
.tr_end{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr class="tr_lista">
      <td>nome 1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">pag1</td>
      <td>obs1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">data1</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Ver mercadorias"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tr_end">
      <td colspan="5">
         <textarea rows="7" cols="90" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">mercadoria1</textarea>
      </td>
   </tr>

<tr class="tr_lista">
<td>nome 2</td><td style="text-align: center;">pag2</td>
<td>obs2</td><td style="text-align: center;">data2</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Ver mercadorias"/></td>

</tr>
<tr class="tr_end">
<td colspan="5">
<textarea rows="7" cols="90" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">mercadoria2</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Passe uma referência para a `function`, do elemento que disparou o evento por exemplo usando `this`:

```
<input type="button" value="Ver mercadorias" onclick="ver_endereco(this);"/>
```

Isso fará com que chegue na `function` o `input` que foi clicado.
Então você pode usar a `closest` do *JQuery* para obter o elemento pai do botão mais próximo que tenha a classe *tr_end*, assim:

```
function ver_endereco(botao){
    $(botao).closest("tr.tr_end").toggle();
}
```

Referência: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

**EDIT:** no seu exemplo, a `TR` com a classe "tr_end" está após a `TR` onde está o botão que vai ser clicado. Se for esse mesmo o cenário, `closest` não vai funcionar, se quiser selecionar o próximo elemento, deve usar `next` no lugar de `closest`: https://api.jquery.com/next/